# Checking user session in HTML files in golang

Tags: session, go

How to check the user login session directly in the HTML files? I already searched it on google but I can't find the checking session directly in the html file, is it not possible to do that?

The only thing I can found is by pass it through `ExecuteTemplate()`, is that the only thing I can do?

Comment: What do you mean by call cookie value? Would you please give a use case?

Comment: @leafbebop ah sorry, I make myself unclear, I already edited it

Comment: So you want to access the session in the browser? You can use JavaScript to do so.

Comment: @leafbebop there are no function in go to get the session like PHP does?

Comment: PHP just generated it into HTML just like you passing the variable into template.There are no better options than that as far as I know, but there are better templates such as fasttemplate.

Comment: @leafbebop I see, then I'll start writing some JS then, anyway, do you know how to get the values from `gorilla/sessions`? I'm using `session.Values["ID"] = 1` to set, and I think to get that value just write `session.Values["ID"]` but it doesn't work, I read the docs but didnt find the right function. Do you know about it too?

Comment: I think you are doing it right. Maybe you forget to do a type assertion? What error do you get? It is hard to debug without these information.

Comment: @leafbebop I already do a type assertion like this `session.Values["ID"].int`,   this is the error what I got **session.Values["ID"].int undefined (type interface {} is interface with no methods)**

Comment: It's `.(int)` not `.int`.

Comment: @leafbebop ah I forgot about the () brackets, that's why it's error. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I think from your description you have a session variable accessible within the .go file (the handlerfunc), and wish to use it in the html file. This is relatively simple, it's just a value. Yes, passing it through ExecuteTemplate is the right approach. The session is just a cookie sent with the request to your server from the browser, it's there in the request headers.

You could set a func in your set of funcs for the template which accessed some sort of global variable, but then you'd get into problems with syncing across goroutines (every request handler runs in a goroutine), so the simpler approach is best.

You should not be trying to perform operations on the session in a template like decrypting it and extracting a user id - this is more suited to your handlers and far more secure there and not in the template.

First extract it from the cookie using your preferred library (you are encrypting your sessions right?), then add it to the view context (let's say you use a map of values).

```
// use a lib like gorilla sessions
session, err := store.Get(r, "session-name")
userID := session.Get("user")

// store data (here in a map[string]interface{})
data := make(map[string]interface{})
data["userID"] = userID 

// Send this data to the view
t.Execute(w, data) // Sets the . variable in templates
```

Then in the view, just use something like this to access the values you need:

```
{{ .userID }}
```

Alternatively yes you can just use javascript to access the session, but you'd need to know how it is encrypted, which is probably a security hole if it contains any information of value - anything js can get at your user can get at too.

Comment: what if the template is header template? should i do this for all method?

Comment: Hi @kreamik I am having the exact same issue and have been searching everywhere, do you manage to find a way to check for the user session in a template?

Comment: Like the ansers above, i duplicate the session for every page

Answer (score 0):

Templating is by far the most universal approach. There are third-party alternatives to ExecuteTemplate, such as https://github.com/valyala/quicktemplate.

An alternative is to do "client-side templating" where ALL of the renderings are done on the client using JavaScript and communicating to the server using a REST-like/JSON API.

***Which should I choose?*** That depends on your use case. If your website needs live updates and does a lot of back-and-forth with the server, client-side scripting can make things significantly easier so you only have to have a JavaScript function to render part of the page, not a JavaScript function *and* an equivalent Go function. It can also create a smoother overall interface; for example, if an action takes a few seconds to "process," client-side templating and rendering *can* be built so the page doesn't have to completely refresh (thus avoiding the "flash of white" while the page refreshes).

On the other hand, if you have a simple application, server-side templating will be faster to build (you don't have to build an API) and result in a faster overall page load time.

---

Of course, rarely is an application all client-side or all all-server side. Reading URLs in JavaScript is difficult, so I have seen people using a templating engine to inject an object ID into a JavaScript constant. Even with an all client-side approach, using a templating engine to standardize navigation/footer/site layout between all pages (rendering all of the templates when the server starts up) is useful.